# I want to alter table in php , but my code is not working

Tags: php, mysql, alter-table

I want add another column into my table using PHP my code is not working

```
$sql="ALTER TABLE user_preference_table ADD column '$tag_id' VARCHAR(60) ";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

i think problem is with my way of declaring the variable into the query ?

is my query right?

```
'$tag_id'
```

it is a variable that contains the some id like 501

Comment: i would recommend you to do some research on SQL-Injection

Comment: Without knowing what `$tag_id` is, how are we supposed to answer?

Comment: Also, can you provide error messages, further information? Please edit them into your question and not in the comments.

Comment: Remove the single quotes around your column name.

Comment: i'm getting no error while executing this query but database is also not affecting

Comment: 501 isn't a valid column name. look at the documentation. maybe you should reconsider your database layout if you want to dynamically add columns to your tables at runtime...

Comment: it is working thank u $sql="ALTER TABLE user_preference_table ADD column `$tag_id` VARCHAR(60) ";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace single quote with backtick.

```
$sql="ALTER TABLE user_preference_table ADD column `$tag_id` VARCHAR(60) ";
```

Signle Quotes are generally for inserting values into Database tables.

Backticks are used for DB fields.

They prevent errors of using [reserved keywords](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysqld-version-reference/en/mysqld-version-reference-reservedwords-5-0.html) in MySQL.

e.g.

```
as
from

...etc
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$sql="ALTER TABLE user_preference_table ADD column `".$tag_id."` VARCHAR(60) ";
```

Comment: pls check I have modified it

Comment: no bro it did not work and i changed like Programming Student said it is working now

Answer (score 0):

You no need to use column and '' Please try this

```
$sql="ALTER TABLE user_preference_table ADD  $tag_id VARCHAR(60) ";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

Comment: Please try now i made same mistake as you did :(

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to create the column with numeric value '501'. I think you should add some character before $tag_id.

Try this:

```
$tag_id.='F'.$tag_id;

$sql="ALTER TABLE user_preference_table ADD column '$tag_id' VARCHAR(60) ";
```